# .NET: Example code for EZCAD 2

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb6

I have read some thread about EZCAD right here : [Loading a C++ DLL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707859/loading-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp)

But I do not find a solution code from the author. Is there someone who can give an example of code themselves?

Comment: Just read the link you submited in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading a C++ DLL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707859/loading-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
public Test

{

[DllImport("myunmanaged.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

private extern static int UnmanagedFunction(int type, int dest);

}
```

Comment: I dnot have EZCAD2 SDK