# make c++ class in a native dll to use in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, pinvoke, wrapper

I spent about 3 days reading about this topic...

I am totally lost now thanks to the many tutorials and answered questions about how to create a native DLL. If you have some time to spare please care to explain a little about the topic and help me - if you don't have time then just go to the simple form of my question down there...

---

Here is what I know about the topic so far:

1) I need to use a macro defined as `__declspec(ddlexport)` and `__declspec(ddlimport)` before class name to export all the class methods and variables

2) I need to use `extern "C"` somewhere but I am not sure exactly where

3) There are many ways to do this (pass class as parameter to methods that accept it c approch/ export class / use interface)

---

Here is why and how I am lost:

1) Most of tutorials are for exporting methods, which I suspect is very easy compared to classes (in C# you use [Dllimport, name of DLL] then you invoke each method)

2) Do i need to use `extern "C"` with classes or not?

3) If I used a factory method with an interface do i need distribute the .h file containing the interface?

---

Here is what i want to do:

1) create a C++ DLL with a class in it and to export that class to be used in .NET or C++ (I want to protect my code, since I saw how easily you can reverse managed code using the stored IL.)

2) I want to have 2 DLLs, one C++ native DLL, and the other one will be the wrapper DLL, so that if someone wants to use my class in C++ he can use the native DLL directly and if he wants to use it in C#/VB.net he can use the C++/CLI wrapper DLL...

3) no libs, no header files, no def files,...etc..... only pure DLLs (2 files will be released)

---

### Simple form

---

Let's say I want to instantiate an object in C# from this C++ class

```
Class Human
{
 private:
    int Pee_Meter;
 public:
    Void Do_Pee()
       {
         //stuff here
       };
};
```

What do I need to do,  basic stuff only? With the least possible number of files and maximum code protection, no releasing of header files or anything, only using DLLs and probably a txt file that mention methods names and stuff to use in DLL.

In other words, are these steps correct?

1) In VS2012 create new Win32 project, then select DLL as type of project

2) define macro `__declspec(ddlexport)` / `__declspec(ddlimport)` and use it before class name (should I use `extern "C"` with classes? Probably not...)

3) Compile DLL

4) Create a CLR project in VS2012 to use C++/CLI

5) Link the native DLL (I don't know how?? `PInvoke` entire class???????)

6) Define wrapper class (which I am still learning, but I think you create a method in CLI for every method in native class)

7) Compile the CLI DLL

Should I say that I have Deitel and Ditel C // Deitel and Ditel C++ // C++ programming by D. S. Malik and non of these three books mention anything about making DLLs which I think is kind of stupid.

Finally, thank you for every second you wasted in helping me, I really appreciate every help you provide even if you directed me toward a tutorial that I have read before... I might have missed something in it :)

Comment: You should probably get comfortable with DLLs and linking before trying to make a C++/CLI wrapper (and no, you don't need PInvoke if you are doing that, just link and use).

Comment: Get yourself a copy of [C++/CLI in Action](http://www.manning.com/sivakumar/). This answers the questions you're having about the interop part. As for DLLs, the MSDN has relevant documentation: [Dynamic-Link Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589.aspx).

Comment: I answered something like this a while back... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672351/calling-c-function-from-c-with-lots-of-complicated-input-and-output-paramete/15685123#15685123

Comment: Wow learning all c, c++, c++/cli, c# using libraries in one step - you should start with tiny steps!

Comment: @crashmstr probably you are right... maybe my problem is linking and not the actual definition and declaration of classes

Comment: @IInspectable thanx i will see if I can get a copy of it

Comment: @MadScienceDreams thanx for the link Iam viewing it right now

Comment: @Dieter Lücking yeah ^^ but I know C++ took a course in which we covered classes/Inher/Operators overloading/ abstract classes/ other stuff it is just iam new to dll and linking in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having done this a bunch of times, the easiest way to do this is to write a C++/CLI wrapper to your existing classes.  The reason being that P/Invoke works best on calls that are strictly C functions and not methods in a C++ class.  In your example, how would you call `operator new` for the class that you specify?

If you can write this as a C++/CLI dll, then what you get is something that looks like this:

```
public ref class CliHuman {
public:
    CliHuman() : _human(new Human()) { }
    ~CliHuman() { delete _human; }
protected:
    !CliHuman() { delete _human; }
public:
    void DoPee() { _human->Do_Pee(); }
private:
    Human *_human;
};
```

Now, you might not have the freedom to do this.  In this case, your best bet is to think about what it would take to expose a C API of your C++ object.  For example:

```
extern "C" {

void *HumanCreate() { return (void *)new Human(); }
void HumanDestroy(void *p) { Human *h = (Human *)h; delete h; }
void HumanDoPee(void *p) { Human *h = (Human *)h; h->Pee(); }

};
```

You can P/Invoke into these wrappers very easily.

From an engineering standpoint, you would never want to do this ever since calling .NET code could pass in any arbitrary IntPtr.  In my code, I like to do something like this:

```
#define kHumanMagic 0xbeefbeef;

typedef struct {
    int magic;
    Human *human;
} t_human;

static void *AllocateHuman()
{
    t_human *h = (t_human *)malloc(sizeof(t_human));
    if (!h) return 0;
    h->magic = kHumanMagic;
    h->human = new Human();
    return h;
}

static void FreeHuman(void *p) /* p has been verified */
{
    if (!p) return;
    t_human *h = (t_human)p;
    delete h->human;
    h->human = 0;
    h->magic = 0;
    free(h);
}

static Human *HumanFromPtr(void *p)
{
    if (!p) return 0;
    t_human *h = (t_human *)p;
    if (h->magic != kHumanMagic) return 0;
    return h->human;
}
void *HumanCreate() { return AllocateHuman(); }
void HumanDestroy(void *p)
{
    Human *h = HumanFromPtr(p);
    if (h) {
       FreeHuman(p);
    }
    else { /* error handling */ }
}
void HumanPee(void *p)
{
    Human *h = HumanFromPtr(p);
    if (h) h->Do_Pee();
    else { /* error handling */ }
}
```

What you can see that I've done is create a light wrapper on top of the class that lets me verify that what comes in is more likely to be a correct pointer to what we want.  The safety is likely not for your clients but for you - if you have to wrap a ton of classes, this will be more likely to catch errors in your code where you use one wrapper in place of another.

In my code base, we have found it especially useful to have a structure where we build a static library with the low-level code and the C-ish API on top of it then link that into a C++/CLI project that calls it (although I suppose to could P/Invoke into it from C# as well) instead of having the C++/CLI directly wrap the C++.  The reason is that (to our surprise), all the low-level code which was using STL, was having the STL implementations done in CLI rather than in x86 or x64.  This meant that supposedly low-level code that was iterating over STL collections would do something like 4n CLI transitions.  By isolating the code, we worked around that quite well.

Comment: first thank you very much for you time in writing that answer and sharing the idea on how to avoid the problem about passing arbitrary intptr. but what do you mean by "you might not have the freedom to do this"? I have read that certain data types cant be passed as return/parameters between C++ and CLI, is that what you mean?

Comment: If your requirements are "ship exactly 1 dll, has to work in both C++ and from a C# project", then you can't use a C++/CLI wrapper (I don't think).

Comment: not 1 dll, 2 dlls are what iam looking for 1 native and 1 wrapper... and it turns out that my problem is in linking the native dll with the CLR project and not declaration/approaches. anyway iam searching right now and reading about how to link native dlls...

Comment: okey Iam giving up on the only 2 dlls part... will include a header file too... i thin that wont change alot about how much is my code protected... i will create the wrapper class as you instructed. thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off making a plain C interface to your C++ code.  C++ linking is really only good for other C++ programs, due to [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).  C functions, however, can be used in many languages without any problem - python, C#, haskell, etc.

Let's suppose, however, you want to have some C++ classes accessible from your C interface.  The way I like to do this is:

- in my C++ dll have a global object registry.  basically a map from int to object.
- whenever I create an object, it gets a new registry ID.
- whenever I call a function that uses the object, I pass in the ID.

so something like this:

```
int CreateNiftyInstance()
{
   int i = global_store.get_id();
   Nifty *n = new Nifty();
   global_store.save_obj(i, n);

   return i;
}

void DoSomethingNifty(int id, const char *aCData)
{
   // lame dynamic cast.  Making it type safe is possible with dedicated stores for 
   // each type of object.
   Nifty *n = dynamic_cast<Nifty*>(global_store.get_obj(i));
   if n
   {
      n->DoSomething(aCData);
   }
}
```

Comment: you mean `(global_store.get_obj(id)` ?? so ,forgive my limited mind, but are you suggesting to make an interface in the same C++ project and mark it as extern "C"?? instead of making a wrapper class?? will the client/user of my dll use the methods in my class by passing the Obj/ID as a parameter? or is there something iam missing? like... do you mean the C Language Approach mentioned here [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL] ... thank you very much Bzzt for your time.

Answer (score 0):

ah i think I found what I was looking for after reading this [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9405/Using-classes-exported-from-a-DLL-using-LoadLibrar]

correct me if wrong

1. first I need to either export the native class or mark a factory method as extern "C"
2. then in the CLR project I use the factory method or use Loadlibrary + malloc commands to get an instance of the class if I did not go with the factory method approach
3. create the wrapper class as plinth had told me to do (many thanx to him). and use the instance from the previous step to call methods in my class
4. include both dlls in the release and instructe developers to reference the CLR dll only.

if that is the way then iam very greatfull for all of you guys

going to start working on it soon...

Yours...