# Converting C++ pointer struct to C#

Tags: c#, c, pointers

I have 2 structs in C language:

```c
struct CSquare
{
    char Side;
    int  Row;
    int  Col;    
};

struct CSide
{
   char     m_Side;           
   char     m_Blocks[3][3];     
   CSquare  *m_Moves;
};
```

and C++ code:

```c
int Count = 0;
int Flag = 0;
if (m_Down->m_Blocks[0][1] == *m_Down)
{
    Count++;
    Flag |= 2;
    // type of m_Down is CSide
}
```

I'm trying to convert they to C#:

```cs
public class Square
{
    public char Side { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }   
    public int Col { get; set; }
}

public class CubeSide
{
    private char Side { get; set; }
    private char[,] _block = new char[3, 3];
    private Square[] moves;

    public char[,] Block
    {
        get { return _block; }
        set { _block = value; }
    }

    internal Square[] Moves
    {
        get { return moves; }
        set { moves = value; }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to convert line:

```c
if (m_Down->m_Blocks[0][1] == *m_Down)
```

to C#?

How can I convert this line to C#?

Comment: Careful with the `char` in C to `char` in C# conversion. They can have a different meaning. `char` in C# really means a unicode character. And what exactly is `m_Down`?

Comment: I'm missing, m_Down is CSide.

Comment: `m_Down->m_Blocks[0][1] == *m_Down` looks strange for me, except there's an overloaded operator.

Comment: What is the logic behind this code?

Comment: Is the code for something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368699/deep-copying-an-array-c-sharp-without-serialization)?

Comment: You have a type error there, I think. `m_Down->m_Blocks[0][1]` is of type `char`, while `*m_Down` is of type `CSide`

Comment: @ZachJohnson: It *might* be error, but if there's an overloaded operator of `==`, then it's no problem.

Comment: @KenKin yeah, just guessing the overload might be to compare the m_side field...? We need more info.

Comment: @Dirk a `char` in C# is a UTF-16 code unit, not a Unicode character `</pedantic>` (but yes, in either case, it is quite different from C++'s `char` which is defined to be a byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line make no sense, i guess it's always evaluate to false.

What you can do is to set a breakpoint on that line and perform a quick watch, evaluate *m_Down to make sure there's no overload operator.

Then, evaluate the condition. Depending on your type of project, put some printf("inside the if")/printf("inside the else"), messagebox or write it in a file. If the condition is evaluate to true, print the value of m_Down->m_BLocks[0][1]  and *m_Down...

Make sure you first understand the logic behind this line. Once you understand it, it will be easy to write it in c#

PS: in C#, use Byte instead of Char